# nivo slider issue

Tags: jquery, css, nivo-slider

I used nivo-slider in my web page. I need to implement many nivo-slider in my single page. I have successfully implement it. But, if i click the previous icon total slider images were changed. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: yeah. I have changed the ID in all slider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is probably the same id usage. You should have different id's for different sliders.

After you change the id names, you will also need to make adjustments to your nivo function in javascript to accommodate new ids

For example if this is your code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function () {
        jQuery("#slider").nivoSlider()
    });
</Script>
```

It should be like this for three sliders with ids : slider-1, slider-2, slider-3

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function () {
        jQuery("#slider-1").nivoSlider()
        jQuery("#slider-2").nivoSlider()
        jQuery("#slider-3").nivoSlider() 
    });
</Script>
```